# keep object from moving out of the canvas

Tags: javascript

1. The blue object on my game is controled by the keyboard keys(A, z, s, w) but the object keeps going out of the canvas, how do i keep it within the canvas?
   Do not worry about the yellow object

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;

function startGame() {
 myGamePiece = new component(40, 80, "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)", 20, 100);
 myObstacle = new component(20, 20, "yellow", 20, 60);
 myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 580;
        this.canvas.height = 370;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
  this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e){ 
       myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
    myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
  
  window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e){ 
       myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
  })
    },
 clear : function() {
      this.context.clearRect(0,0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
   }
}
function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.gamearea = myGameArea;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
 this.speedx = 0;
 this.speedy = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;  
    this.update = function(){ 
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
 }
 this.newPos = function() {
     this.x += this.speedx;
  this.y += this.speedy;
  }
}
function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
 myObstacle.update();
 myGamePiece.speedx = 0;
 myGamePiece.speedy = 0;
 if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys  [65]) {myGamePiece.speedx = -5;}
 if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys  [83]) {myGamePiece.speedx = 5;}
 if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys  [87]) {myGamePiece.speedy = -5;}
 if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys  [90]) {myGamePiece.speedy = 5;}
 myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

</script>

<p>The start game</p>

</body>
</html>
```

1. The blue object on my game is controled by the keyboard keys(A, z, s, w) but the object keeps going out of the canvas, how do i keep it within the canvas?
   Do not worry about the yellow object

Comment: What's wrong with `W`, `A`, `S` and `D`?

Answer (score 1):

Before update the position, check if the new position is within bounds.

In particular, you should check if the new value for `x` is greater or equal to`0`, if it isn't don't update `x`. The same goes for `y`.

The upper bound is a bit trickier, because it requires checking using the size of the object. What you would have to do is check if `width` plus the new value for `x` is lesser or equal to the size of the world, if it isn't don't update `x`. Do the equivalent for `y`.

---

Currently your code reads as follows:

```
this.x += this.speedx;
this.y += this.speedy;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
this.x = this.x + this.speedx;
this.y = this.y + this.speedy;
```

Now, `this.x + this.speedx` and `this.y + this.speedy` are the new values for `x` and `y`, respectively. We could rewrite this as follows:

```
let newx = this.x + this.speedx;
let newy = this.y + this.speedy;
this.x = newx;
this.y = newy;
```

So far, we have just been refactoring the code. This should do exactly the same as before.

Let us go over what I said:

> you should check if the new value for `x` is greater or equal to`0`, if it isn't don't update `x`

Which is the same as saying: only update `x` when the new value for `x` is greater or equal to `0`. Alternatively, in code:

```
let newx = this.x + this.speedx;
let newy = this.y + this.speedy;
if (newx >= 0)
{
   this.x = newx;
}
this.y = newy;
```

> The same goes for `y`.

```
let newx = this.x + this.speedx;
let newy = this.y + this.speedy;
if (newx >= 0)
{
    this.x = newx;
}
if (newy >= 0)
{
    this.y = newy;
}
```

> check if `width` plus the new value for `x` is lesser or equal to the size of the world, if it isn't don't update `x`

Another way to say that is: only update `x` when `width` plus the new value for  `x` is lesser or equal to the size of the world. Alternatively, in code:

```
let newx = this.x + this.speedx;
let newy = this.y + this.speedy;
if (newx >= 0 && this.width + newx <= this.gamearea.canvas.width)
{
    this.x = newx;
}
if (newy > 0)
{
    this.y = newy;
}
```

> Do the equivalent for y

```
let newx = this.x + this.speedx;
let newy = this.y + this.speedy;
if (newx >= 0 && this.width + newx <= this.gamearea.canvas.width)
{
    this.x = newx;
}
if (newy > 0 && this.height + newx <= this.gamearea.canvas.height)
{
    this.y = newy;
}
```

Go ahead, copy paste that, it should work... *unless I misunderstood your code*. Yet, I would like to encourage you to understand what is going on here. Otherwise you will be moving ahead with a gap in your understanding that will come back to bite you.

---

For these kind of game development you need to think in terms of dimensions. In this particular case, we can solve the problem by considering each component separately... consider the following:

[image: Visualization of the object on both extremes]

*You should not allow a value of x lesser than zero - You should not allow a value of <strike>y</strike> x such that x + width is greater than the width of the world.*

As you can see in the image, the value of `x` must always be greater than `0` and be such that `x + width` is smaller than the width of the world.

In other words, `x` must be in the interval `[0, (width of the world) - width]`.

The equivalent is true for `y`.

These requirements come from the behavior you want to model (you do not the object to go out of bounds) and defining it without ambiguity (give values to those bounds, so you can check them in code).

---

Note: The speed you have is in pixels per frame, if your frame rate changes it will affect how much the object moves. This is because you are not using the elapsed time between frames... but that is not the topic at hand. In addition, handling collision is another topic.

Comment: Thank you so much, but i am very new in this and still a student so i do not really understand what you want e to do with that unless you explain with coding so i can know where my mistake is. thank you once more.

Comment: @F.Celes Updated. While I understand learning by example, making sense of what a person want and modelling it in code is pretty much what programming is... and therefore something worth practice. When using a modern platform you would have to go out of your way to cause any problem, so do not be afraid of trying. Well, do backups just in case.

Comment: Theraot, you are a Hero!!! Thank you very much for opening a new window in my mind on this, i tried to send to you a personal message on this site but seems there is no interface for that, Is there anyway i can contact you directly? (If you permit of course)

Comment: @F.Celes there is something similar to that in this site, but it is behind a reputation wall (namely: creating chat rooms for particular groups of users). Which reminds me that comments are not itended for extended discussion. My contact info is in my profile, under the developer story. I would like to invite you to try [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) there you will have better chances of finding help with questions related to game development. Edit: try searching, perhaps it has already been asked.

Comment: Hello Theraot, hope you are doing ok, i made a little progress but now i dont know how to go ahead, the idea i have is to creat as many of those yellow little boxes and let them fall from top, then with control keys i run away from them with the blue object, then once it hits the blue object it should be a game over.

Comment: @F.Celes if what you need is collision detection, in the most basic sense it is the same as I explaned here... but you check backwards. I mean, you don't want to check if the block is going out of the world, but if it is going into an obstacle. It is the same logic, but you check the opposite (instead of checking for going outside, check for going inside), so you flip ">" and "<".

Answer (score 0):

In `newPos` function you should increment x only until x + width is lower than canvas width. Same for y you should increment it until y + height is less than canvas height.

And decrement until x and y are greater than 0.

I hope it makes sense, otherwise please ask.